# What is the worst case complexity of max() function inside a for loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I have seen the complexity of max() is O(N).
While in program snippets(at geeksforgeeks) I had seen the complexity of such following code is O(N).
But how's that's possible if inside for loop these is another function of O(N).
So the total complextity should be O(N^2).
Please explain what's correct and how?

```
int x(vector<int> nums){
    int tmp;
    for(auto i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
        maximum=max(nums);
        cout<<maximum;
    }
}
```

Comment: This snippet isn't particularly cleaver, each interation is computing the same value each time. `i` isn't used in the loop. The complexity of this is obviously `O(N^2)`. 
Are you sure that is is the snippet you saw?

Comment: Well, I guess Geeksforgeeks is wrong. If the worst case complexity of `max(nums)` is `O(N)`, then calling it in a loop over `nums` will be `O(n^2)`

Comment: The above code is just plane wrong - does not compile;  `int tmp;` not used; `maximum` not declared; `i` iterating the array but not being used to index it. Please post some real code and check it compiles 1st.

Comment: Geeksforgeeks is known for low quality, bad code style and wrong information. This is an example for unclear or wrong information. You should avoid that website.

Comment: How does the max() function look like?

Comment: @al3c this is a similar, This is the real one https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-second-largest-element-array/   here at the second solution they wrote max function and after solution complextiy is given n

Comment: @RichardCritten here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-second-largest-element-array/     in The second solution max function is used inside for and then after solution it is written Time complexity O(n);

Comment: @jabaa Can u suggest me where should i learn things?

Comment: You should use books. Articles on geeksforgeeks are written by people without much knowledge and experience (junior students or hobby programmers). Books are usually proof read. I also avoid books from https://www.packtpub.com/ because many books there (all I've read) seem to have a similar low quality as articles on geeksforgeeks. There are many publishers for technical books with very high quality.

Answer (score 1):

> Please explain what's correct

The time complexity of the shown function is O(N*N)

> and how?

The function with linear complexity is called a linear number of times.

In **theory**, a compiler could be smart enough to know that `max` returns the same value and has no side-effects, and in such case would automatically memoize the result which would result in O(N) complexity. But in practice such proof is often too hard for compilers.